# Get Value From Dynamic Component in Blazor

Tags: c#, dynamic, blazor

I am trying to use the new dynamic component feature released in .net 6. I have watched all the videos on youtube and done the examples. I simply cant seem to figure how to get a value back from the component. I have used the Parameters Property of the dynamic component tied together with an event, but my use case will be to have a bunch of dynamic components loaded on to the page and the submit button is part of the parent page and not the dynamic components. When submit it clicked, I just want the value from the textbox dynamic component on the parent page. Heres an example :

TextBoxComponent

```html
@Label: <input type="text" style="margin: 5px;" @bind-value="@TextBoxValue"/> 
@code{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string TextBoxValue { get;set; }
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Index Page:

```html
@page "/"
@if (type != null)
{
        <DynamicComponent Type="type"  />
}

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SaveToDatabase">Submit</button>

@code {
    Type type;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        type = typeof(TextBoxComponent);
    }

    private void SaveToDatabase()
    {
        // get the text value of the dynamic component and insert into db
    }
}
```

I have tried creating an object called Appstate and assigning a string property but still I cant get the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For learning about Blazor, I recommend the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0#event-callbacks-eventcallback). What I describe below comes directly from the documentation.

I modified your example in 2 ways:

1. One way is to use `@ref` to get a reference to the component and then access the `TextBoxValue` property. Once you have a reference to the component, you can get to the `TextBoxValue` property like this:
   `(dc?.Instance as TextBoxComponent)?.TextBoxValue;`
   *Note that the `?` is because I am using nullable reference types.
2. The second way is hooking up an `EventCallBack` by passing it through the `Parameters` parameter.

I also added two text fields, `Text1` and `Text2` so you can see how the updated is being done when you run this example.

---

```
@Label: <input type="text" style="margin: 5px;" @bind-value="@TextBoxValue" @oninput=OnInputCallBack /> 

@code{
    public string? Label { get; set; }
    public string? TextBoxValue { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs> OnInputCallBack { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
@page "/"

@if (type != null)
{
    <DynamicComponent Type="type" @ref="dc" Parameters="parameters" />
}

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SaveToDatabase">Submit</button>

<h3>@Text1</h3>

<h3>@Text2</h3>

@code {
    Dictionary<string, object>? parameters;
    Type? type;
    DynamicComponent? dc;
    string? Text1;
    string? Text2;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        parameters = new() { { "OnInputCallBack", EventCallback.Factory.Create<ChangeEventArgs>(this, GetInput) } };
        type = typeof(TextBoxComponent);
    }

    private void GetInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Text2 = (string?)e.Value;
    }

    private void SaveToDatabase()
    {
        Text1 = (dc?.Instance as TextBoxComponent)?.TextBoxValue;
    }
}
```